# How to toggle visibility of nested list on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a nested lists:

```
<ol id="warningType">
<li id="Other">Other
   <ul class="toggle_menu">
   <li>Create() is conflict with Delete() when you are creating.</li>
   <li>View() must have the same parent with Delete().</li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li id="Input">Input
   <ul class="toggle_menu">
   <li>Get() can be the input of Create().</li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li id="Exception">Exception
   <ul class="toggle_menu">
   <li>If you forget to delete all elements, Post() will throw Error A.</li>
   <li>View() will throw IllegalException.</li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ol>
```

I would like to click "Other""Input" and "Exception" to get or hide the nested list. Any help with it would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of putting images, please post your minimal code here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this accordion :

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
button.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Animated Accordion</h2>
<p>Click on the buttons to open the collapsible content.</p>

<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and
provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Hi, @RVCoder what is the relationship between <div class="panel"> and button? Is button <div class="panel">'s parent?

Comment: button and div are siblings in my case but you can restructure as well

Answer (score 0):

It is called Accordion, and actually  it's not neccessary to insert  tag into li tag. Here is example.
Your html:

```
<ul class="accordion">
    <li>
        <h3>Section 1</h3>
        <p>Text 1 of  this section Lorem ipsum.</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h3>Section 2</h3>
        <p>Text 1 of  this section Lorem ipsum.</p>
    </li>

    <li>
        <h3>Section 3</h3>
        <p>Text 1 of  this section Lorem ipsum.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Css:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #009788;
}

ul.accordion {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 5% auto 0 auto;;
}

.accordion > li {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.accordion li > h3 {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #d6d6d6;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.accordion li > h3:hover {
    background: #ccc;
}

.accordion li > h3:after {
    content: "+";
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2%;
}

.accordion li > p {
    display: none;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #d6d6d6;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
}

.accordion li h3.active:after {
    content: "-";
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
```

and Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('h3').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
        $(this).siblings().not(':animated').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am still confused how to use the Jquery code in my javascript, can you explain it a little bit more?@Genjik

Comment: I will try to explain in the jquery code above which I gave you. First I select h3 tag by jquery and add event which executed when someone click on the h3 tag. Then we have css class ".active" which is the style of activated h3, and we add toggle method in jquery, which add .active class for h3 if there is not or vice-versa. Also we set <p> tag a style which set display: none; In last code of jquery we select sibling of h3 tag, in this case it is <p> and toggle display attribute to block or none;

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via accordion

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
        Other</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="toggle_menu">
   <li>Create() is conflict with Delete() when you are creating.</li>
   <li>View() must have the same parent with Delete().</li>
   </ul></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
        Input</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body"><ul class="toggle_menu">
   <li>Get() can be the input of Create().</li>
   </ul></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
        Exception</a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body"><ul class="toggle_menu">
   <li>If you forget to delete all elements, Post() will throw Error A.</li>
   <li>View() will throw IllegalException.</li>
   </ul></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is using bootstrap's collapsible accordion